# AdMob ads not displaying in Xamarin Android application

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, admob

I have recently managed to complete and deploy my first Android app to Google Play, and now I am trying to add AdMob.

After a few false starts, several clean-ups and rebuilds I am at the point where the application is building but I can't get the ads to display.

So, I have created a content view called AdMobView;

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class AdMobView : ContentView
    {
        public AdMobView()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And then following class;

```
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MyApplication;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;


[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdMobView), typeof(AdMobRenderer))]

namespace MyApplication
{
    public class AdMobRenderer : ViewRenderer <AdMobView, AdView> 
    {
        protected override void    OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdMobView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var ad = new Android.Gms.Ads.AdView(Forms.Context);
                ad.AdSize = Android.Gms.Ads.AdSize.Banner;
                ad.AdUnitId = "<the AdUnit id>";

                var requestbuilder = new Android.Gms.Ads.AdRequest.Builder();
                ad.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());

                SetNativeControl(ad);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the XAML where I want the ad displayed, I have added

```
<controls:AdMobView WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="50" />
```

Also in this XAML, I have added an xmln for the control

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApplication;assembly=MyApplication"
```

In the MainActivity.cs I have added

```
MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, "<the AdUnit id>");
```

In the AssemblyInfo.cs I have added;

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessNetworkState)]
```

In AndroidManifest.xml I have added;

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

So, as I said, this builds fine and runs in debug mode on both a real device and in emulator, but  there is nothing in the area the ads should show.  i can just see the normal background - there isn't even a "blank" box.

If anyone has any ideas, you could save me a few sleepless nights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have managed to get it working.
In case anyone else is struggling, I'm going to post the full code here, as I did not find one tutorial which worked by itself and had to piece together from several sources...

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   package="<your package name>" 
      android:versionCode="<your version code>" android:versionName="<your version number>" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:label="<your app title>" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</application>
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
 using Android.Gms.Ads;
 .
 .
 .
 MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, "<your unit id>");
 LoadApplication(new App());
```

Important Note - make sure this is the app unit id and not the app id which look similiar.  The unit id is the one which has format 
ca-app-pub-9nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn/nnnnnnnnnn
The app id looks similiar but has a ~ instead of a /
If you are using a LoadApplication in the main activity, make sure this is after the Initialize - thats one of the schoolboy errors i was making.  In VS2015 this actually has a green underline with a message stating it is deprecated, but I found it still is required for ads to be served.

Create a View called AdMobView.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace FightJudgeAssistant
{
    public class AdMobView : View
    {

    }
}
```

when you create a view in Visual Studio, it puts in different Using statements.  You can get rid of all these and just have the Using Xamarin.Forms

Create a class called AdViewRenderer.cs:

```
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using FightJudgeAssistant;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(mynamespace.AdMobView),     typeof(AdMobRenderer))]

namespace mynamespace
{
public class AdMobRenderer : ViewRenderer<mynamespace.AdMobView, Android.Gms.Ads.AdView>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<mynamespace.AdMobView> e) 
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            var ad = new Android.Gms.Ads.AdView(Forms.Context);
            ad.AdSize = Android.Gms.Ads.AdSize.Banner;
            ad.AdUnitId = "<your unit id>";

            var requestbuilder = new Android.Gms.Ads.AdRequest.Builder();
            ad.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());

            SetNativeControl(ad);
        }
    }
}
```

}

On the screen you want to display the ad (in my case its an XAML within a grid view):

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<Grid x:Name="controlGrid" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <controls:AdMobView Grid.Row="6"/>
    </Grid>
```

I have other content in the grid rows not shown above.  You'll notice I have set the row height for row 6 to be "auto" instead of "*" to ensure the ad takes up as much space as required.

Also added the following XMLNS in the ContentPage section:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:mynamespace;assembly=myAssemblyname>
```

And thats about it!  To test this worked I used ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 which is specifically for testing banner ads

Comment: What exact path I should add xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:mynamespace;assembly=myAssemblyname ??

Comment: will the ad display on an emulator?

Comment: This actually stopped working and I never got round to fixing it, having other projects to work on.  I'll try getting back to it someday and update the answer

Answer (score 0):

This should still work. You need to change the way of Ad initialization.

from

```
MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, "<your unit id>");
```

to

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="YourAppID"/>
```

place this into your app manifest